# Camera view along the trajectory

Tags: differential-equations, graphics3d, animation

I want to create an animation like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rvzZmNW2_70

After googling I have found just below informations about this issue: https://twitter.com/bencbartlett/status/1278424544848621578 https://twitter.com/InertialObservr/status/1175188246734573568

I am not sure about the mathematical background of the animation. One of the comments refers to Frenet–Serret formulas:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet-Serret_formulas.

The creator of the animation gave this information:

> I put the camera at r(t-δt) + (r' × r'') and had it point toward r(t)
> + r'(t).  The δt adds lag so you follow behind the path of the particle, the (r' × r'') offsets the camera above the plane normal to
> the particle's curvature, and the r(t) + r'(t) points to where it's
> going.

I need help with Mathematica commands relating to camera options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some experiments I got similar picture, but final animation is too large for this forum. So I have created small animation just to show a principle of visualization. First we have created all needed vectors

```
L = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -3 (x[t] - y[t]), 
    y'[t] == -x[t] z[t] + 26.5 x[t] - y[t], z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - z[t],
     x[0] == z[0] == 0, y[0] == 1}, {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, 
   MaxStepSize -> 0.001];

n = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -3 (x[t] - y[t]), 
    y'[t] == -x[t] z[t] + 26.5 x[t] - y[t], z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - z[t],
     x[0] == z[0] == 0, y[0] == 1}, 
   Cross[{x'[t], y'[t], z'[t]}, {x''[t], y''[t], z''[t]}], {t, 0, 
    100}, MaxStepSize -> 0.001];
L1 = NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == -3 (x[t] - y[t]), 
    y'[t] == -x[t] z[t] + 26.5 x[t] - y[t], z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - z[t],
     x[0] == z[0] == 0, y[0] == 1}, {x'[t], y'[t], z'[t]}, {t, 0, 
    100}, MaxStepSize -> 0.001];
```

Then we make scene and frames

```
LA = ParametricPlot3D[L, {t, 0, 60}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u}, ColorData["NeonColors"][u]],
   PlotPoints -> {100, 100}]
gr[t1_] := 
 Show[{LA, 
   Graphics3D[{Specularity[White, 4], Sphere[L /. t -> t1, .3]}]}, 
  Background -> Black, ImageSize -> {300, 300}, 
  SphericalRegion -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

Finally we create animation

```
ListAnimate[Table[Show[gr[t1 + .1], 
   ViewVector -> {(L - 3 n /Norm[n]) /. {t -> t1}, 
     L1 /. t -> t1 + .1}], {t1, 0.6, 1.65, .009}]]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Your first solution was already good but after your edit it become fantastic. Thank you so much.

Comment: @MustafaKösem You are welcome!

Answer (score 7):

If anyone wants to build on top of this answer, feel free. We start by draw the Lorentz attractor:

```
solutions[tmax_] := NDSolveValue[{
   x'[t] == -3 (x[t] - y[t]),
   y'[t] == -x[t] z[t] + 26.5 x[t] - y[t],
   z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - z[t],
   x[0] == z[0] == 0,
   y[0] == 1
   },
  {x, y, z},
  {t, 0, tmax}
  ]

{xsol, ysol, zsol} = solutions[100];

plot[tend_, tmax_] := Rasterize@Show[
   ParametricPlot3D[
    {xsol[t], ysol[t], zsol[t]},
    {t, 0, tend},
    PlotRange -> {{-15, 15}, {-25, 25}, {-10, 50}},
    ColorFunction -> Function[
      {x, y, z, u},
      ColorData["SolarColors", 1 - (tend - u)/tmax]
      ],
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
    PlotPoints -> 100,
    Background -> Black,
    Boxed -> False,
    Axes -> False
    ],
   Graphics3D[{
     White,
     Sphere[{xsol[tend], ysol[tend], zsol[tend]}]
     }
    ]
   ]

frames = plot[#, 100] & /@ Subdivide[1, 100, 1000];

ListAnimate[frames]
```

[image: Output]

The animation only shows the first 100 frames, I had to cut it down in order to save space. Anyway, this is a plot of the Lorentz attractor where the curve fades in color over time (the further from the tip of the curve, the darker).

To position the camera, one can use `ViewVector` together with `FrenetSerretSystem`, as Tim suggests in his answer. That looks like this:

```
basis = Last[FrenetSerretSystem[{xsol[t], ysol[t], zsol[t]}, t]];

r = {xsol[#], ysol[#], zsol[#]} &;
origin[u_] := r[u - 0.1] + 0.1 (normal /. t -> u)
target[u_] := r[u] - 0.1 (tangent /. t -> u)

(* Put this into the plot function defined earlier *)
ViewVector -> {origin[tend], target[tend]},
ViewRange -> {-.01, 1000}
```

Flinty helped me out with `ViewRange` in a comment below. Without it, the line would be broken and it wouldn't look good.

I wish that I could here show a brilliant looking animation, but unfortunately it turns out that even when you have all the pieces in place, it's hard to get it to look good. The camera positioning given by `origin` and `target` will make the camera follow the tip of the curve, but that alone is not enough to make it really good looking. The author of the animation that you link to in your question must have spent a lot of time tuning things. Also, he seems to be using a nice framework that makes glow possible. The glow part would be very hard to implement in Mathematica.

Comment: You can fix the clipping by adding `ViewRange -> {-.01, 1000}`

Comment: @flinty Thank you! That's it. Seems like something needs to be done about the view vector but at least it works in principle now.

Answer (score 6):

There are some examples of how to control the camera in the downloadable notebook of the Wolfram U tutorial [Dynamic Visualization in the Wolfram Language](https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/catalog/vis434/).  You probably want to use a combination of `ViewVector`, `ViewVertical`, and `ViewAngle` to control the camera.  Use ViewVector to view ahead and `ViewVertical` to orient the camera.  In the example below, I set the `ViewVertical` to be given by the normal of the [`FrenetSerretSystem`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrenetSerretSystem.html).

```
knot = KnotData["Trefoil", "SpaceCurve"];
basis = Last[FrenetSerretSystem[knot[t], t]] // Simplify;
(* Space Curve Normal *)
n[t_] = basis[[2]];
{tangent, normal, binormal} = 
  Map[Arrow[{knot[t], knot[t] + #}] &, basis];
Manipulate[{Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[knot[s], {s, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick], 
    Graphics3D[{Thick, Blue, tangent, Red, normal, Purple, binormal}],
     PlotRange -> 3], 
   Show[ParametricPlot3D[knot[s], {s, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thick], 
    PlotRange -> 6, ViewVector -> {knot[t - 0.01], knot[t]}, 
    ViewVertical -> n[t - 0.01], ViewAngle -> 90 Degree]} // 
  Evaluate, {t, 0, 2 Pi, Appearance -> {"Open"}}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Top]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

@Sumit. As can be seen from the code below, only the ViewPoint parameter is not enough. More camera parameters are required.

```
R = 1;
f[x_] := Sin[x];
w[x_] := Normalize[{1, f'[x], 0}];
u[x_] := Normalize[Cross[w[x], {0, 0, 1}]];
v[x_] := Cross[w[x], u[x]];
path1[x_] := {x, f[x], 0} + R u[x];
path2[x_] := {x, f[x], 0} - R u[x];
pipe = ParametricPlot3D[{x, f[x], 0} + R Cos[t] u[x] + 
    R Sin[t] v[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}];
curve1 = ParametricPlot3D[{x, f[x], 0} + R u[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Purple, Dashed, Thickness[0.02]}];
curve2 = ParametricPlot3D[{x, f[x], 0} - R u[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Green, Dashed, Thickness[0.02]}];

Animate[
 Row[
  {Show[{pipe, curve1, curve2, 
     Graphics3D[{PointSize[.1], 
       Switch[Sign[Sin[x/2]], 
        1, {Purple, Point[path1[x]]}, -1, {Green, 
         Point[path2[x - 2 Pi]]}]}]}, ViewPoint -> {-0.8, 1.4, 3}, 
    ViewVertical -> {0.2, 1.8, 1}, ImageSize -> 400],
   Show[{pipe, curve1, curve2, 
     Graphics3D[{PointSize[.1], 
       Switch[Sign[Sin[x/2]], 
        1, {Purple, Point[path1[x]]}, -1, {Green, 
         Point[path2[x - 2 Pi]]}]}]}, 
    ViewPoint -> 
     Switch[Sign[Sin[x/2]], 1, path1[x], -1, path2[x - 2 Pi]], 
    ImageSize -> 400]}], {x, 0, 4 Pi}]
```

Comment: You also need `ViewCenter`, or you can use `ViewVector` which combines the two of them.

Answer (score 1):

You need `ViewPoint`

As an example here is how you move on a sphere along the great circle `{Cos[a Pi], 0, Sin[a Pi]}`

```
Manipulate[ SphericalPlot3D[1, {theta, 0, Pi}, {phi, 0, 2 Pi},
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ViewPoint -> {Cos[a Pi], 0, Sin[a Pi]}], {a, 0, 2, 0.1}]
```

[image]